# Behavior of Javascript map when we return inside callback

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

We normally use "map" in Javascript to get a new and transformed array. It is different in this case.
Here is a piece of code from a Service Worker definition. It is intended to delete old caches and keep only the newest version.
My main focus in on what happens inside "cacheNames.map". Because, at some point, we will enter the "if" statement. Basically, when an old cache is alrealdy stored an a new cache is taking its place.
My questions are:
1- What happens when you have a "return" statement inside a callback that is being used by "map"? i.e. return caches.delete(cache) 
2- Will the remaining iterations stop when "return" is executed for the first time?

```
caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
  return Promise.all(
    cacheNames.map(cache => {
      if (cache !== cacheName) {
        console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
        return caches.delete(cache);
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: "*We normally use "map" in Javascript to get a new and transformed array*" - and so you do here. The array is transformed to an array of `undefined`s (when the callback didn't return anything) and deletion promises.

Comment: I would suspect that both of those questions could be answered by trying to run the code (or code similar to it).

Comment: "*What happens when you have a "return" statement inside a callback that is being used by "map"?*" - you seem to know how `map` works (for transforming arrays) already, so shouldn't you be able to answer this yourself? Or what makes you think it would work differently here?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I understand now. We dont keep in this case, the new transformed array as we would in a basic use. We just use the "iteration" functionality of "map" to check if a condition is met within an array of keys. Many thanks for your super-fast response.

Comment: @jet2016 No, you don't just use the iteration functionality. You also use the new transformed array as an argument to `Promise.all`, which is important. Using e.g. `forEach` would not have worked.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. `Promise.all` gets the new array, but I see it is going nowhere. It is not being used at all. In fact, I removed the line `return Promise.all` and tested the service-worker and works fine. This is a piece of code I saw on youtube which could be slimmed down. The key line in this piece of code is `return caches.delete(cache)` and even here, the `return` is not needed.

Comment: @jet2016 Doesn't `caches.delete(…)` return a promise? Don't you use the result of the outer `then` promise chain?

Comment: @Bergi  `caches.delete(…)` returns a boolean depending on deletion success/fail. In the end, it's just a piece of code I found on youtube that could be optimized / improved / slimmed down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is the same inside or outside of a callback.

`map` returns a new list based on an old list. `return` inside the mapping function decides what the element (`cache` in this case) is replaced by. In the cases where nothing is explicitly returned using `return`, `undefined` is implicitly returned instead.

And no, `return` has no effect on the remaining iterations of `map`. Again, it simply decides what the new element value will be.